# VQcache is always empty

Tags: xml, opencart, vqmod

I am working on opencart and using vqmod for modifying files. My problem is that is not loading files in vqcache and nothing is changing on site. I get some times this error in xml > logs.

**"VQMod::_parseMods - INVALID XML FILE: : CData section not finished"**
this error is obviously coming because XML format is not fine, but i have checked everything and its fine. Every tag is started and finished, every search string is fine.

I have long xml file i will attach that if required.

xml > log errors

> REQUEST URI : /
>   VQMod::_parseMods - INVALID XML FILE: : String not started expecting ' or " in /var/lib/openshift/55ff118b2d5271ec7c0000a7/app-root/runtime/repo/vqmod/xml/vqmod_hx_customer_portal.xml, line: 1
>
> REQUEST URI : /
>   VQMod::_parseMods - INVALID XML FILE: : Document is empty in /var/lib/openshift/55ff118b2d5271ec7c0000a7/app-root/runtime/repo/vqmod/xml/vqmod_hx_customer_portal.xml, line: 1

Comment: https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/#Opencart-Vqmod-not-working - check this link.

Comment: @SankarV i have followed each step everthing is upto the mark still the same. I have updated my errors in question please view

Comment: Identify which `<file` section in that xml causes the error by adding/removing `<file` sections in that xml.

Comment: after deleting mod.cache and checked.cache from root it ran...